# data retrieve from mysql to JTable

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

i am working with JTable and mysql connectivity.in mysql i have a table called studentmaster in that table the fields are Studid,StudNo,StudName,Stud mrk1,Stud Mrk2,Stud Tot,Stud Res.I need to get StudName,Stud mrk1,stud mark2,stud tot,stud res in JTable using resultset.i did not find how to set those field values alone into JTable so guide me to set those values alone into JTable using ResultSet.the code i used was

```
package student;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class student1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    // public Connection Conn;
    Vector data = new Vector() ;
    Vector columnNames= new Vector();


    public student1() {
        initComponents();
        Connection conn;

    }
 public void Connection(){
      try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String username = "root";
String password = "root";
String Database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Database, username, password);
System.out.println("*** Connect to the database ***");


Vector<String> Columns = new Vector<String>();
Vector<Vector<Object>> Rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
String Query = "Select * from  StudentMaster";
PreparedStatement smnt = conn.prepareStatement(Query);
ResultSet results = smnt.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData metaDt = results.getMetaData();
//(metaDt);

int cols = metaDt.getColumnCount();
Columns.clear();
//System.out.println("database" +cols);
for(int i=1;i<cols;i++){
    columnNames.addElement (metaDt.getColumnName(i));
}
Rows.clear();
 while(results.next()){
     Vector row= new Vector(cols);
     for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++){
         row.addElement(results.getObject(i));
        }

     data.addElement(row);
 }
results.close();
smnt.close();

conn.close();
    }
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
}

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);

        jButton1.setLabel("New");

        jButton2.setMnemonic('N');
        jButton2.setText("jButton1");

        jButton4.setText("jButton1");

        jButton3.setText("jButton1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jButton1, jButton2, jButton3, jButton4});

        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanel2Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jButton1, jButton2, jButton3, jButton4});

        jButton2.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Id", "No", "Name", "Class", "Subj 1", "Subj 2", "Total", "Result"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(708, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1016, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
        java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        java.awt.Dimension dialogSize = getSize();
        setLocation((screenSize.width-dialogSize.width)/2,(screenSize.height-dialogSize.height)/2);
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new student1().setVisible(true);
               student1 s1=new student1();
               s1.Connection();

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to restrict your query to the desired columns: `SELECT StudName,Stud_mark1,stud_mark2,stud_tot,stud_res  FROM StudentMaster`?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ResultSetandJTable.htm) will be useful for you.